# Automatically send email about editing google spreadsheet

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I'm working on a rather simple script which should handle new values in the spreadsheet and then send emails to specified addresses. And I faced with the problem. My code is listed below:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //part of the code for checking e.range to process only updated values
  sendEmail();
}
function sendEmail() {
  // arguments are missed only for demo
  GmailApp.sendEmail();
}
```

While I'm using "simple trigger", my function "sendEmail()" works only if I start it from script editor. I allowed sending emails on behalf of my at first time and then function works fine. But if I'm changing the value in the spreadsheet - function "onEdit(e)" processes new data but function "sendEmail()" does nothing.

I partly solved this problem by using project's triggers from "current project's triggers" menu. In that case, function "sendEmail()" works properly, but I have no access to the information about update.
For my purposes I could use just second way and find new values "manually" every time, but I wish to optimize this work.

So, my questions are:

1. Is the process I described above proper or I made a mistake
   anywhere?
2. If process proper, is where a way to combine both cases?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much - I missed this in the documentation. The problem is solved)

Comment: @soup maybe you will repost your comment as an answer and I'll mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You correctly understood that ([as the docs say](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions)) simple triggers cannot send an email, because they run without authorization. An [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), created via Resources menu, can: it has the same rights as the user who created the trigger.  If it is set to fire on edit, it will get the same type of [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) as a simple trigger does.

So, a minimal example would be like this, set to run "on edit":

```
function sendMail(e) {
  MailApp.sendEmail('user@gmail.com', 'sheet edited', JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

It emails the whole event object in JSON format.

Aside: if your script only needs to send email but not read it, use MailApp instead of GmailApp to keep the scope of permissions more narrow.